# Illegal mix of collations when running stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very long stored procedure and I keep getting the following error:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

It's occurring on some databases but not others but when I run `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, all of the collations are set to `latin1_swedish_ci`

Does anyone have any advice on how to debug this? Is there a way to determine where in the stored procedure the error is coming from so I can try to pinpoint the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In **MySQL**, collation can be set at different levels.

- Database level
- Table level
- Column level

Apart from that collation can also be set at the **server** and **connection** level to MySQL.

Therefore, Check the collation type on various levels and make sure that they have the same collation. You can check the collation by:

**Database collation**

```
SELECT default_collation_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = '<schema_name>';
```

**Table collation**

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_collation FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '<schema_name>';
```

**Column collation**

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, collation_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '<schema_name>';
```

Collation for the server, connection, and database

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
```